# Primitive roots of unity and $I$-adically separated rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, roots-of-unity

Let $R$ be an integral domain with $\operatorname{char}(R) = 0$ and let $\zeta, \zeta'$ be two primitive roots of unity in $R$. The following are equivalent.

(1)  $(q-\zeta)^m \in (q-\zeta') + I[q]$ for some $m \geq 0$ and an ideal $I \subset R$ such that $R$ is $I$-adically separated (note: $(q-\zeta')$ on the right side denotes the ideal generated by $q- \zeta'$).

(2) $R$ is $(\zeta-\zeta')$-adically separated.

(3) $\operatorname{ord}(\zeta^{-1}\zeta') = p^k$ for some prime $p$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ such that $R$ is $(p)$-adically separated.

I believe I have just the implication (2) $\implies$ (1). If $R$ is $(\zeta-\zeta')$-adically separated, then $\cap_{j\geq 0}(\zeta-\zeta')^j = (0)$. We have to show that $(q-\zeta)^m \in (q-\zeta') + I[q]$ for some $m \geq 0$ and an ideal $I \subset R$ such that $R$ is $I$-adically separated. But
$$q-\zeta \in (q-\zeta') + (\zeta-\zeta')[q]$$
since $q-\zeta = (q-\zeta') + (\zeta'-\zeta)$.

I sort of "have" the proof of the reciprocal, (1)$\implies$ (2), but I don't understand a step. The author says that since $(q-\zeta)^m \in (q-\zeta') + I[q]$ for some $m \geq 0$ and $I \subset R$ such that $R$ is $I$-adically separated, then $(\zeta-\zeta')^m \in I$. This is what I don't find obvious at all. From that I believe the result follows since the ideal generated by $(\zeta - \zeta')^m$ would be then contained in $I$, so 
$$\bigcap_{j\geq 0}(\zeta-\zeta')^j \subset \bigcap_{j\geq 0}I^j = (0)$$
and hence $R$ is $(\zeta-\zeta')$-adically separated.

For any of the implications (2)$\implies$(3) or (3)$\implies$(2) I literally have no clue. Any hero would be nice. Thank you!

Comment: What is $q$? And $I[q]$?

Comment: @xarles sorry I couldn't answer earlier. $q$ is a variable, just like $s$ or $t$. $I[q]$ is then the set of polynomials with coefficients in $I$.

Comment: For the equivalence of (2) and (3), I would start by rewriting $(\zeta - \zeta') = (1 - \zeta^{-1}\zeta').$ Now, in algebraic number theory, there are standard arguments showing that if $\xi = \zeta^{-1}\zeta'$ is a primitive $p^k$th root of unity, then $1 - \xi$ is the unique prime over $(p)$ in $\Bbb Q(\xi).$ I would mimic this argument to show that $(1 - \xi)^r = (p)$ for some $r$ (or some similar relation between the ideals), and the result you want should follow without too much trouble once you have the relationship between the two ideals.

Comment: @Stahl Thank you for the hints. I didn't see the relation $(\zeta - \zeta') = (1 - \zeta^{-1}\zeta')$, but it is clear now. I see how the result follows from the relation $(1 - \zeta)^r = (p)$, but I am unable to prove this relation. Could you please expand your comment or provide a reference to the argument you mention?

Comment: The argument was a little too long for a comment, so I posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the minimal polynomial (over $\Bbb Z$) of a primitive $p^k$th root of unity $\zeta$ is $$f(x) = \prod_{i\in\left(\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z\right)^\times} (x - \zeta^i) = x^{p^{k-1}(p-1)} + x^{p^{k-1}(p-2)}+\cdots + x^{p^{k-1}} + 1.$$   Evaluating $f$ at $x = 1$ gives $\prod_i (1 - \zeta^i) = p.$

Now, for any fixed $i,$ $1 - \zeta^i = \epsilon_i(1 - \zeta),$ where $$\epsilon_i = \frac{1 - \zeta^i}{1 - \zeta} = 1 + \zeta + \dots + \zeta^{i - 1}\in R.$$ In fact, $\epsilon_i$ is a unit of $R$! Indeed, let $j$ be such that $ij\equiv 1\pmod{p^k}.$ Then we compute $$\epsilon_i^{-1} = \frac{1 - \zeta}{1 - \zeta^i} = \frac{1 - \zeta^{ij}}{1 - \zeta^i} = 1 + \zeta^{i} + \dots + \zeta^{i(j - 1)}\in R.$$ Thus, at the level of ideals we have
$$
(p) = \prod_i (1 - \zeta^i) = \prod_i (1 - \zeta) = (1 - \zeta)^{\varphi(p^k)}.
$$

More refined arguments may be found in most books on algebraic number theory; for example, in chapter 1 section 10 of Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory.*

---

For the implication (2)$\implies$(3), we note that we simply must show that $\xi = \zeta^{-1}\zeta'$ is a primitive $p^k$th root of unity. Indeed, once we have this, the previous argument showing $(1 - \zeta_{p^k})^{\varphi(p^k)} = (p)$ proves that $R$ is $p$-adically separated.

We will prove the contrapositive: we will assume that $\xi$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, where $n$ is not a prime power, and prove that $R$ is not $(1 - \xi) = (\zeta - \zeta')$-adically separated. In fact, we shall prove that $(1 - \xi) = R.$

Let $p$ be any prime dividing $n.$ Then $\xi^r = \zeta_p$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity for some $r$, and
$$
\frac{1 - \zeta_p}{1 - \xi} = \frac{1 - \xi^r}{1 - \xi} = 1 + \xi + \dots + \xi^{r - 1},
$$
so that $1 - \zeta_p\in(1 - \xi).$

Now, because $(1 - \zeta_p)^{p - 1} = (p),$ it follows that $p\in (1 - \xi).$ If $\ell$ is another prime dividing $n,$ the same argument shows that $\ell\in (1 - \xi)$ as well. Elementary number theory tells us that there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$
1 = ap + b\ell.
$$
But writing $p = u(1 - \xi)$ and $\ell = v(1 - \xi)$ for some $u,v\in R,$ it then follows that
\begin{align*}
1 &= ap + b\ell\\
&= au(1 - \xi) + bv(1 - \xi)\\
&= (au + bv)(1 - \xi)\\
\implies 1&\in (1 - \xi).
\end{align*}

So, if multiple primes divide $\operatorname{ord}(\xi),$ we have $(1 - \xi) = R,$ and
$$
\bigcap_i (1 - \xi)^i = \bigcap_i R = R,
$$
which implies $R$ is not $(1 - \xi) = (\zeta - \zeta')$-adically separated (as $R$ is not the zero ring).

---

While I'm at it, I'll try to clear up the confusion about the argument provided that shows (1)$\implies$(2).

> ...since $(q−\zeta)^m\in(q−\zeta')+I[q]$ for some $m\geq 0$ and $I\subseteq R$ such that $R$ is $I$-adically separated, then $(\zeta - \zeta')^m\in I$.

This is shown by simply evaluating at $q = \zeta'.$ Indeed, $(q−\zeta)^m\in(q−\zeta')+I[q]$ means precisely that
$$
(q - \zeta)^m = P(q)(q - \zeta') + Q(q),
$$
where $Q(q)\in I[q]$ and $P(q)\in R[q].$ Notice that $(q - \zeta)^m = \pm (\zeta - q)^m,$ depending on whether $m$ is even or odd, so that
$$
(\zeta - q)^m = \tilde{P}(q)(q - \zeta') + \tilde{Q}(q),
$$
where $\tilde{P}\in R[q]$ and $\tilde{Q}\in I[q].$ Setting $q = \zeta',$ we find
$$
(\zeta - \zeta')^m = \tilde{P}(\zeta')(\zeta' - \zeta') + \tilde{Q}(\zeta') = \tilde{Q}(\zeta')\in I,
$$
because each coefficient of $\tilde{Q}$ is in $I.$ The rest of your reasoning showing that $R$ is then $(\zeta - \zeta')$-adically separated is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I can see how this proves the implication $(3) \implies (2)$, but I don't see how $(2) \implies (3)$ follows from this, since the assumption that $\zeta$ is a $p^k$-th root of unity seems crucial.

Comment: @user313212 I've edited the answer to include an argument showing (2) implies (3)

Comment: This is simply excellent! I wish I could upvote this answer a hundred times more. Thank you very much for this!